# Counting number of values in each bin : Python

Tags: python

**workbook dataframe**

```
Scores     Score Bins   
22         (0, 25] 
54         (50,75]
209        (200, 225]         
0          (0, 25]
```

I am unable to **find the number of values corresponding to each bin**.
For example I **want to find out how many values are in bin** (0, 25], (25, 50] etc.

**Output I want**

```
Number of values in bin (0,25]: _____
Number of values in bin (25,50]: _____
and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the `value_counts` method:

```
workbook['Score Bins'].value_counts()
```

It will return a pandas Series with counts for each unique value of the specific column, f.e.:

```
(200, 225]    25
(175, 200]    25
(150, 175]    25
(125, 150]    25
(100, 125]    25
(75, 100]     25
(50, 75]      25
(25, 50]      25
(0, 25]       25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
workbook['Score Bins'].value_counts()
```